# User copying questions to other forums, then copying replies back to the original question

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

There seems to be a user who copies questions to a different forum, then collects the answers there and posts them back to the original question. Is this accepted behaviour? If not, what could we do with it?

For some examples, see the report at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1198857

Comment: Flag the answer for a moderator, start with *Plagiarism* and then explain the post is copied verbatim without attribution  with a link to the original.

Comment: @rene Would mods notice that the user is a "serial offender" if they handle single/individual flags for each post?

Comment: I flagged each reply and comment mentioned in the report.

Comment: Ah... I see what's going on. And yes, it's endemic. The user has done it with several other questions, to which he's posted plagiarized *answers*. It is being handled now...

Comment: @Tom when you tell them, yes. When I'm traversing a user profile I mention  something like *this is the third plagiarism flag for the same user* etc. If there are blatant cases where a lot of posts need to be checked mods might call for help and decide on the process to follow. This happened a few times on SO where the SOCVR chatroom was asked to help out.

Comment: @rene Yes, thats a good idea to explicitly mention that this isn't the first flag for similar cases. Good to know.

Comment: If you see any plagiarized posts in the profile that I missed, please raise a flag on them. I cleaned up the recent stuff as best I could, but it's possible I missed something. The influx has now ceased, which is the important thing.